# Third-party library not loading in Expression Engine 2.0

Tags: php, expressionengine

I'm developing a properties module for Expression Engine that's to take properties from Rightmove's BLM format and populate a database, and then those properties be searchable from the front-end.

I've found a CodeIgniter library (http://biostall.com/codeigniter-rightmove-blm-parser-library) that does the heavy lifting of the BLM files. However, I can't seem to load it.

My code in mcp.properties.php looks like this:

```
$config = array();
$this->EE->load->library('rightmove_v3_parser');
$this->rightmove_v3_parser->initialize($config);
$data['properties'] = $this->rightmove_v3_parser->process();
print '<pre>'; print_r($data['properties']); print '</pre>';
exit;
```

The library files are in a `libraries` sub-folder in my `properties` add-on folder under `/system/expressionengine/third_party/`.

However, when using the above code, I get the following error in Expression Engine:

> > **A PHP Error was encountered**
> >
> > Severity: Notice
> >
> > Message: Undefined property: Properties_mcp::$Rightmove_v3_parser
> >
> > Filename: properties/mcp.properties.php
> >
> > Line Number: 44
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function initialize() on a non-object in /Users/Martin/Sites/expressionengine/system/expressionengine/third_party/properties/mcp.properties.php on line 4

Where am I going wrong? Why can't I bundle this library with my add-on and call it within my add-on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed the EE object when referencing the library.  So after loading the library you should use

```
$this->EE->rightmove_v3_parser
```

to access it, rather than

```
$this->rightmove_v3_parser
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the library at the top of your plugin, i could be wrong but I don't think loading a library like that will work from a library subdir in your third_party plugin folder. Try including the library at the top of your plugin.